# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given in laravel

Tags: laravel

I can register properly, but when I am going to login then here is an error like -

`The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given`

In my LoginController -

```
public function login(Request $request){
    Sentinel::authenticate($request->all());
    return Sentinel::check();
}
```

In web.php

```
 Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
if(Sentinel::check()){
    // authenticated

} else {
    // not authenticated
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And please visit - [sentinel manual](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#sentinel-check)